# Error - The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am not an Android Developer and Java is sort of Alien to me.

I was building my first react-native-app and was building a splashscreen which requires you to fiddle with Android

So, I was reading this article on the web to [create a splashScreen](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae)

When I ran my app, it threw an error saying that

> The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not
>   allowed.

The directory which It pointed to have an issue is consist just few lines of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">white</color>
</resources>
```

Which still happens to be the equivalent of [what author have done](https://gist.github.com/spencercarli/11d373afa6c2f7d6ee01cd559f30dbf0#file-colors-xml)

The complete error would be

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > /Users/anilbhatia/Desktop/Crypto-Main/Crypto-frontend/android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml:2:6:
> >     Error: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is
> >     not allowed.

**Question:** How to fix it or what I would've done wrong here? Also I am not sure what all code I need to share so please spoon feed me if I need to share additional details.

**Update:** Okay, It looks like that problem have been solved, I had a blank line before start of my XML. There shouldn't be anything before the XML and I was also having color code problem (check answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the color value instead of color name so use (change the name of the color )

```
 <color name="blue">#ffffff</color>
```

or you can use inbuilt colors as

```
 <color name="blue">@android:color/white</color>
```

Tip: click on the color icon on left to open the color picker

Comment: That didn't work, same error :\ 
Thanks for answering though

Comment: Okay, I guess I solved it. I had a blank line before start of my XML. There shouldn't be anything before the XML

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say that but I thought you posted the whole code already, this the `XML` standard that the XML file should be started with the tag for parsing purposes

Comment: I started `<xml` on newline  (the line 1 was just blankline) so when I pasted the code here, SFO automatically formatted it and removed it. 
Anyway thanks for answering and helping.

Comment: oh optimisation, I am glad that I could help, happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

The XML Color tag takes in an hexadecimal value, not a name.

So use this to get a blue color

```
<color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
```

and then call it using `@color/blue` in your XML file
Alternatively you can use android's color values using `@android:color/holo_blue_dark` if you don't wanna define your custom color

Comment: that didn't work. Same error 
Thanks for answering though